# When it is safe to use `isalpha()`

Tags: c++, ascii, glfw

I have [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/) `key_callback()` and I'm trying to detect if an alphabetic character is pressed. I use this function [isalpha()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha). I've noticed that some keys such as Shift and Alt are treated as alphabetic characters if I perform the following code:

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                                                         

int main()
{
    // 340: printed int if the Shift key is pressed.
    if( isalpha(340) )
        std::cout << "alpha"     << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "not alpha" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The preceding code yields `alpha`. I can validate the range of integers that are passed to the function but this makes no sense since I'm not taking advantage of the function. **My question** is is it safe to pass any integer to that function and use simple if-statement to validate alphabetic characters? What is the precaution need to be taken if any in case using this function?

Comment: I don't understand the comment in your code. Where did you get that magic 340?

Comment: *The behavior is undefined if the value of ch is not representable as unsigned char or is not equal to EOF.* This is undefined behaviour that you are inducing.

Comment: @t0mm13b it says that, but is it actually undefined? In this case it would be 340 % 256 == 84, i.e. T which is clearly alphabetic

Comment: @DavidBowling ah, yes I just saw that it takes an `int` rather than `unsigned char` for one reason or another I thought that it was doing the casting as part of the call

Comment: @NickA the function signature probably dates back to the time when any argument was `int` or `void *` ;)

Comment: @FelixPalmen Not necessarily, if you read the C89 standard, the function is declared as `int isalpha(int c);` So it has unchanged since.

Comment: @FelixPalmen, this is the integer I get if I press Shift key via some key_callback(). I'm using glfw.

Comment: @t0mm13b I think that's what I said and I assume it has this signature because it's *older* than C89.

Comment: @CroCo so you use some kind of library-defined *virtual key code* with `isalpha()`. It's common practice that virtual key codes correspond to the character codes of the current character set, the documentation should state whether this is the case. But in *any* case, key codes can hold more values than character codes (function keys, meta keys, modifiers, etc). You have *at least* to check whether you *have* an actual character before passing it to `isalpha()`.

Comment: @NickA -- yes, the behavior is undefined. That's what the language definition says. It means that the language definition does not tell you what the effect of the code is. "Undefined behavior" does not mean "will do something bad".

Comment: @t0mm13b, so it is unsafe to pass any integer? Why doesn't it return 0 at least  in case non-alphabetic character ?

Comment: @DavidBowling, If I cast it, the result is `T`.

Comment: There isn't a tag for GWLF (which is where I think this `key_callback` comes froms).  Is this a popular enough library that we should add one?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy, the tag for glfw is already there but I thought it is unnecessary to add it.

Comment: @Croco:  I didn't find the tag because I was mistyping it.  Lots of people who know about C++ and `std::isalpha` won't be familiar with `key_callback` and thus wouldn't notice that it gives scancodes rather than characters, so I think the tag would be useful, and I've now added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`key_callback` is not a standard part of C++, so I searched and assume that the one you're talking about is part of the GLFW library.  In that library, the [`key_callback`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/input_guide.html#input_key) gives a keyboard scancode.

Scancodes are not characters.  In a typical input model, there's a state machine that maps scancodes (and sequences and combinations of scancodes) to characters.  This is the layer that would allow you to change your QWERTY keyboard to work like a Dvorak keyboard or like one designed for typing in another language.  This `key_callback` is lower level, and leaves the mapping to you.

The C++ [`std::isalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) function takes a `char` cast to an `int` or a special sentinel value `EOF`, which is typically -1.  (On some systems, you'll find that you need to first cast your `char` to an `unsigned char` before converting it to an `int`.)  Scancodes are not chars, so passing a scancode to `std::isalpha` is meaningless.

In particular, the value 340 is outside the range of an `unsigned char`, and it's not `EOF`, so it really can't be expected to do anything sensible.

If you need chars, you will have to build your own mapping from scancodes (and combinations of scancodes) to chars.  It looks like that library has constants defined for the scancodes. For example, [`GLFW_KEY_LEFT_SHIFT`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__keys.html) is 340.  That should help.  If you just need to know if a particular key is pressed or released, you can compare the scancodes to the appropriate constants.

**Note**:  You tagged the question C++, but you linked to the documentation for the C version of `isalpha`.

Comment: Full of details. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just to summarize the wisdom from the discussion in the comments into a short answer.

1. Your code has [undefined behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) (UB), for reasons discussed in the comments.
2. Therefore, the outcome is unpredictable and most likely incorrect.
3. Code with with UB should be avoided as much as possible.

It's not clear what you mean by `safe`. It's unlikely that it will immediately lead to disaster, but UB in some important code (such as a program controlling an airplane) can do.